# Is it possible to start angular route with a parameter

Tags: angularjs

I have two URLs in my config file like:

```
module.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/:param1', {
                    templateUrl: 'shop.html',
                    controller: 'RouteController'
                }).
                when('/contact', {
                    templateUrl: 'contact.html',
                    controller: 'RouteController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
    }
]);
```

I am using 'param1' variable to fetch data from server. But when I route to '/contact' it considers 'contact' as a variable too and route it to the upper route i.e. variable route. How can I avoid this without using any extra identifier in route1.

Comment: In parameter, router will  work for all parameter. But in your fixed route router will work for that fixed route.

In fixed route : /router1  , if you have a destination of /router1, then it will work.

In parameter : /:param, it will work if you have anytypes of parameter in your route. Be careful for this, because you need verification where you want to go & what will be your goal.

Comment: It routes the first one on to the second and consider route1 as a parameter.

Comment: Please give me full details which you want to know ?